# multiple outputs for webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to separate my react app in two parts. There will be a login page that authenticates a valid user, and once authenticated, I will render the actual web app. For this to happen I figure I will need two html files.

I figure each html file will probably use two different bundles. So my `login.html` would probably use the following script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='./scripts/bundle.js'></script>
```

and my `index.html` will use...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='./scripts/bundle2.js'></script>
```

But how can I output two bundles in webpack?

Here is what I have...

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {'./src'},

  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path:'/',
    filename: 'scripts/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {
    ...etc,etc.
```

As you can see my only entry point is `/src` this is where my current `index.js` file is located to populate my `index.html`.

The `index.js` file used to populate my `login.html` is located in foler `Authentication`. But the following entry won't do what I want...

```
entry: {'./src', '/Authentication'}
```

I need two outputs for each of these html files as they are essentiall separated from one other. What are my options here? Is there a way, or perhaps an alternative, to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty common to split your bundles into multiple files. Webpack's documentation gives a nice explanation for this - [Link](http://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html)

So if you want to have multiple entry points for the app, just pass it as `key: value` pair in the entry point like this:

```
{
    entry: {
        a: "./a",
        b: "./b",
        c: ["./c", "./d"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].entry.js"
    }
}
```

The final files generated will be `a.entry.js`, `b.entry.js` and so on..